# How to convert string to date in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a datafram df_cc_su and I want to compare whether two attributes CalculationDateKey and AgreementStartDate are within the same year-month.

CalculationDateKey samples: 20220331, 20220229, 20220132 (string)
AgreementStartDate samples: 2022-03-17, 2022-02-27, 2022-01-01 (date format)

I tried to convert the string values in CalculationDateKey to datetime:

```
df_cc_su['CalculationDateKey_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cc_su['CalculationDateKey'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

which resulted in all '1970-01-01 00:00:00.020220331' values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format="%Y%m%d"`, because not `/` separator in your data, also `20220132` not exist, so for wrong values are generated `NaT` if add `errors='coerce'`:

```
df_cc_su['CalculationDateKey_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cc_su['CalculationDateKey'], 
                                                     format="%Y%m%d",
                                                     errors='coerce')
```